# How to receive progress data from a running job?

Tags: powershell

I have a need to run a bunch of tasks in the background in parallel.
These jobs can run for hours .

But I need all the jobs to give progress while they are running , that the host can read and give a summary of all the jobs at some time interval . For example last task performed and percent completed.

I did a bunch of searching but I didn't find anything on how the host and all the jobs can communicate at run time to achieve my goal.

How to do this with jobs , or are their other way to run things in parallel that facilitate this ?

Comment: Depends on what you're running. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample project here: https://key2consulting.com/powershell-how-to-display-job-progress/

It uses Write-Progress in the job to output the status and a loop that monitors the job and displays a progress bar.

Your jobs would need to be designed to output % complete. I.e. Your job would need to know when it is 20% complete.

Comment: Pretty sure OP wants info from the jobs, not just a progress bar. But yes, he needs to code some outputs to do this.

Comment: I  read about that .  But this might scale to maybe a dozen  or so jobs not 80 or more   I need a means for jobs to  communicate their progress and then a cmdlet on the host to receive it so the interval and progress specifics can be more controlled.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that does not use progress bars. Your jobs still need to report their progress with periodic writes. If the jobs return data, the data should be stored to a file or other destination. This code reads and discards the returned data as the returned text is used in the update messages.

A better solution could let each job write the status messages to a SQL table and a simple looping screen reads and displays that data. The job's default response is still ready for Receive-Job

For demo purposes only...

```
#load your jobs here... Note that they periodically report their status.
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {$i = 0; 1..10 | foreach { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; $i++; "LoopA $($i*10)% complete"  }; Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {$i = 0; 1..10 | foreach { Start-Sleep -Seconds 2; $i++; "LoopB $($i*10)% complete"  }; Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {$i = 0; 1..10 | foreach { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3; $i++; "LoopC $($i*10)% complete"  }; Start-Sleep -Seconds 1; }



$joblist = @{}  #empty hash table

# get initial list of jobs...
Get-Job | foreach { $joblist.Add( $_.Name, @{ "State"=$_.State; 
                                              "HasMoreData"=$_.HasMoreData;
                                              "LastMsg"="" } ) }

# loop and report status
do
{
  $done = $true
  Get-Job | foreach { 
             Start-Sleep  -Milliseconds 200;    # change for you application
                                                # should be more frequent than job messages
             # collect data from job
             $joblist[$_.Name]["State"] = $_.State;
             $joblist[$_.Name]["HasMoreData"] = $_.HasMoreData;
             if ($_.State -eq "Running") {
               if ($_.HasMoreData) {
                 # get the message from the job
                 $txt = (Receive-Job -Name $_.Name)

                 if ($txt.Count -gt 0) {
                   $joblist[$_.Name]["LastMsg"] = $txt;
                 }
                }
                $done = $false  #still have Running jobs
              }
            }

  # report status
  cls
  $joblist.GetEnumerator() | select Name, {$_.value.State}, {$_.value.HasMoreData}, {$_.value.LastMsg} | ft
} until ($done)

  # final status...
  cls
  $joblist.GetEnumerator() | select Name, {$_.value.State}, {$_.value.HasMoreData}, {$_.value.LastMsg} | ft



# demo clean up.
#Get-Job | Stop-Job 
#Get-Job | Remove-Job
```